# C++ Pointer assignment error

Tags: c++

I have these 2 classes and a test case in the main:

```
class Mytest{
private:
    int var;
public:
    Mytest(int);
};

inline Mytest::Mytest(int a){var=a;}

class ControlClass{
private:
    Mytest* m;
public:
    void f();
};

int main (void)
{
    ControlClass controlobject;
    controlobject.f();
    return 0;
}

void ControlClass::f(){
    Mytest w(5);
    Mytest* c=&w;
    m[0]=*c;// crash line
}
```

and the last line gets me a crash and I do not know why.
please help me

Comment: What's the exact runtime/compilation error? Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Also, your code is hard to read with no indentation.

Comment: m appears to be uninitialized. Either there's code you didn't show, or that's your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't ever allocate memory for your member pointer

```
Mytest* m;
```

it's just an uninitialised pointer, and dereferencing like here

```
m[0]=*c;// crash line
```

leads to undefined behaviour (e.g. resulting in a *crash*).

---

You need to have some memory allocated for `m`, here are some options

```
void ControlClass::f(){
    Mytest w(5);
    Mytest* c=&w;
    m = new MyTest(); // Don't forget to delete in the destructor 
                      // or whenever the resource isn't needed anymore
    m[0]=*c;
}
```

---

```
void ControlClass::f(){
    Mytest w(5);
    Mytest* c=&w;
    static Mytest x;
    m = &x; 
    m[0]=*c;
}
```

Comment: undefined behaviour does not equal crash

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, not necessarily but likely a reason for a _crash_ though.